# Better way to represent the text in the screen

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer, ux-writing

Can someone suggest a better way to represent the text in the two screens in an Android and iOS app. It was designed by developer and I am sure we can do much better. Can we put the text inside the box ? Have a background or something else. Please suggest.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Comment: "Can we put the text inside the box ?" In side what box? I don't see a problem with it as it is. Are you having any problems with it? Another question, what is the left pointing arrow at the top/left, in the red? Is that some sort of back button?

Comment: I was meaning to say if we need to put the text inside some box or card to look better . And yes left arrow is back button.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to understand the *why* behind wanting to change the style other than "we can do better".

Without research, you can only make assumptions about your user. Your contrast ratio is already great. If the user is having trouble reading it, you could make the text larger, instead of putting it in a box.